# How to show error message from eval in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, guile, gambit, kawa

I'm trying to create code that evaluates expression and return error as string for error:

```lisp
(cond-expand
  (gambit)
  (gauche)
  (kawa)
  (guile
   (import (rnrs base)
           (rnrs exceptions)
           (rnrs conditions))
   (define (error-object-message cond)
     (condition-message cond))))

(define (evaluate expr env)
  (call-with-current-continuation
   (lambda (exit)
     (with-exception-handler
      (lambda (e)
        (exit (error-object-message e)))
      (lambda ()
        (eval expr env))))))

;; trigger error
(display (evaluate 'xxx (interaction-environment)))
(newline)
```

I've got

- Guile message `Unbound variable: ~S` how to get actual error message and not a template?
- Kawa exception: `Argument #1 'unbound location: xxx' to 'error-object-message' has wrong type (gnu.mapping.UnboundLocationException) (gnu.mapping.UnboundLocationException cannot be cast to kawa.lang.NamedException)`
- Gauche core dump
- Gambit freezes

NOTE: this is part of REPL that I'm testing in all Scheme implementations that I have on my system. It almost work, it can run itself, but I would like to show proper error message when exception happen, instead of exiting the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

> Gauche core dump

Oops.  It's not ideal, for sure, but it can be explained.

- By default, Gauche's `with-exception-handler` is SRFI-18's, not R7RS's, because of a historical reason.  That means the exception handler is called in the dynamic environment where the exception occurs, *including exception handler settings*.  If an exception occurs within the exception handler, the same exception handler is invoked, causing unbounded recursion.  Apparently Gauche's runtime eats up C stack or something.
- `error-object-message` is not defined in Gauche's default namespace.  So that triggers an exception in the first place.

Add

```
(import (scheme base) (scheme write) (scheme r5rs))
```

at the beginning of code makes the program run in R7RS bindings.   Then you'll get:

```
unbound variable: xxx
```

Actually, your code is not a valid R7RS program (which should begin with at least one `import` declaration), so anything can happen, depending on the default interpretation of the non-conforming code in the implementation.

[Edit] IMHO, `with-exception-handler` should be considered as the lowest level construct on which easy-to-use utilities are built, and thus should be used with extra care.  In general use case, `guard` provides a good abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an infinite loop with Gambit is that the variable `xxx` is unbound so the exception handler `(lambda (e) (exit (error-object-message e)))` is called with an `unbound-global-exception` object and this causes `error-object-message` to be called but the parameter is not an `error-object` (which is specific to the exceptions raised by a call to the `error` procedure) so this raises a `type-exception` object that causes the same exception handler to be called, and so on forever.

If you want an exception handling that "pops" the current exception handler, use `with-exception-catcher` instead of `with-exception-handler`. This will avoid the infinite loop.

Converting an exception object to a string can be done in Gambit this way:

```
(define (exception->string exc)
  (with-output-to-string
    (lambda ()
      (display-exception exc))))
```

It works for `error-objects` and other kinds of exceptions, and also any non-exception object.

This is a more portable solution (superficially tested):

```
(import (scheme base)
        (scheme r5rs))

(cond-expand
  ((or lips kawa gauche)
   (define (exception->string exc)
     (error-object-message exc)))
  (gambit
   (define (exception->string exc)
     (with-output-to-string
       (lambda ()
         (display-exception exc)))))
  (guile
   (import (rnrs base)
           (rnrs exceptions)
           (rnrs conditions))
   (define (exception->string exc)
     (condition-message exc))))

(define (evaluate expr env)
  (call-with-current-continuation
   (lambda (exit)
     (with-exception-handler
      (lambda (e)
        (exit (exception->string e)))
      (lambda ()
        (eval expr env))))))

(display (evaluate 'xxx (interaction-environment)))
(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kawa:

```lisp
   (define (exception->string exc)
     (call-with-port (open-output-string)
                     (lambda (port)
                       (display exc port)
                       (get-output-string port)))))
```

This will convert exception to string and get error message